# Image Change on Hover using CSS

Tags: css, image, html, button, hover

What is wrong with this code? I have been working on this for hours and cannot figure out why the button.png will now show up but the link is there in the location of the "one" div..?

```
#one
{
position: fixed;
left:225px;
top:702px;
}

.button
{
display: block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: url('images/button.png') bottom;
text-indent: -99999px;
}

.button:hover
{
background-position: 0 0;
background-color: transparent; 
border-style: none;
}
```

_

```
<body>
    <div id="map">
        <img src="images/map.png"/>
    </div>

    <div id="one">
        <a class="button" href="images/one.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/button.png"/>
        </a> 
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What are your trying to achieve and what is currently happening?

Comment: Why are you setting the background of the link as well putting an image tag in the link? It seems you could get away with only having the background image (remove the image tag).

Comment: It looks like your HTML is invalid, you've 'double-closed' the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is not really much related to your question .. so I'll just try to answer the question.
The image is not showing, because by default `img` is an inline element and you've set `text-indent` to `-99999px`.
You can either remove that `text-indent` or set the `display` of `img` to `block`:

```
.button img { display: block; }
```

Comment: That did display the image, but now causes the full image to show and not only 40 x 40px of it like I wished.

Comment: `.button img { display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px; }` if you wish to resize the image, if you wish to show a part of it .. what EricL said below:

Comment: add "overflow:hidden" to you link css

Comment: That also worked but now the hover is not working and it is just a normal button.

Comment: Did you remove the img tag? you might just be seeing that because your css only sets the background.. your image tag could be covering the background